# How to insert animation into table?

Tags: java, libgdx, android

I'm having trouble inserting animation into my libGDX table cell.
I have a class which holds 2 tables, one on the left and one on the right. First table is for labels/buttons/other stuff. Second table is for animation, which should change if user clicks a button.

I've created `Animation` class which holds up different animations. The problem is that when I try to add an animation class into the table cell, I get an error because my `Animation` does not extend nor implement `Actor` class, thus I can't insert it into the cell. What should I do? How do you insert class of type animation into table cell?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to extend the Image class yourself and implement the Act method to update the animation state time.

```
public class Animation extends Image{    
    private float stateTime = 0;
    private Animation<TextureRegion> animation;

   public AnimatedActor(Animation<TextureRegion> anim) {
     super(animation.getKeyFrame(0));
     animation = anim;
   }

   @Override
   public void act(float delta){
  ((TextureRegionDrawable)getDrawable()).setRegion(animation.getKeyFrame(stateTime+=delta, true));
super.act(delta);
      }
 }
```

If you want more control over the animation you could even oerride the draw method and draw it yourself.

```
@Override
draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha){
   // draw your animation here
}
```